# How to load list based on internet connectivity changes in xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin

1.I am using Connectivity plugin in xamarin to reload the list. Im using message center to get notified while connectivity changes. My problem is I need to LoadSession only once.

2.The problem is im loading list two times one is in constructor and another from property.how to load list once based on connectivity.

```
private bool isconnect;
  public bool IsConnect
    {
        get { return isconnect; }
        set { SetProperty(ref isconnect, value);LoadSessions(); }
    }`

   `Constructor(){
   MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, bool>(this, "Internet", (sender, arg) =>
        {
            IsConnect = arg;
        });
    LoadSessions();
}
```

Comment: So, clarify a bit. You load a page, then, when the Internet Connectivity changes, you want to LoadSession? Even if its Connected or Disconnected?

Comment: 1. Load Session should be loaded initially. 2.it should be called again when connection changes. Problem is it is called two times. One is from the constructor and another one is from message center IsConnect property triggered.

Comment: Message center will not trigger when connection is down(i.e ISConnect is false).When Internet is off it is loaded only once in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

remove from constructor anche load only when IsConnect becomes true

Comment: the problem is I need to load database list soi called in constructor.i have two lists in load session one is API and another is db list.

Comment: i need to loadsession both in online offline mode.In order to refresh the list i used message center to refresh data based on connectivity

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check your connectivity when you enter the Constructor, and LoadSessions. Only when a change in connectivity, you call LoadSession again, as far as I understood your question. Check this code

```
private bool isconnect;
public bool IsConnect
{
    get { return isconnect; }
    set { SetProperty(ref isconnect, value); }
}

Constructor()
{

    //Assign IsConnected when entering the Constructor
    IsConnect = CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected; //Don't know if you are using this plugin

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, bool>(this, "Internet", (sender, arg) =>
        {
            if(IsConnect != arg)
            {
                IsConnect = arg;
                LoadSessions();
            }            
        });
    LoadSessions();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there is an efficient way other than this?. I'm using this MessageCenter code(Subscribe code) in more than twenty pages of ViewModel.I need to trigger a  property on current ViewModel when connection changes. How to simplify this code?

Comment: If the LoadSession is a Global Method, you can just Subscribe the event in the App ( app.xaml.cs) and then deal with the session. Don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as correct )

Comment: But I'm not using GlobalLoadSession.List varies depend in viewmodel